# Excluding specific string grep is also including similar strings

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am trying to exclude certain entries of URLs (using IPs instead of domain names) in a list with a grep command, specifically to remove all entries starting with `https://` and ending with `:80`. however, entries with `https://` and `:8080` are also being included.

My grep command is:

```
egrep -v "https://[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:80"
```

How can I force grep to only exclude `:80` and not `:8080`

An example of the input file contents is:

```
http://10.10.46.1:80
http://10.10.48.67:8080
http://10.10.48.67:443
https://10.10.46.1:80
https://10.10.48.67:8080
https://10.10.48.67:443
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your input file please? Are the IPs the only thing on the line? Are there any characters after the IPs? What characters? A space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just be a tad more specific in your `grep` command. If the IPs are the only thing on the line, so the `:80` will be the last 3 characters, use:

```
grep -Ev "https://[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:80$"
```

Or, if there can be whitespace after the `80`, use:

```
grep -Ev "https://[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:80\s*$"
```

If the `:80` isn't the last thing on the line, just grep for cases where there is a space after it:

```
grep -Ev "https://[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:80 "
```

If the last character isn't a space, adapt to suit your input.

Comment: Or add a word boundary: `...:80\\>"` -- https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/egrep-regular-expression-syntax.html#egrep-regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Or `grep -x -v ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could condense your regex by taking advantage of the data regularity:

```
egrep -xv 'https?://[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{1,3}){3}:80'
```